# Multiply columns from different data frames if dates match

Tags: r

I have the following two data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Category = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
                  Date = c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003),
                  Beta1 = c(1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 5, 3, 1),
                  Beta2 = c(2, 4, 6, 1, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2))

df2 <- data.frame(Date = c(2001, 2002, 2003),
                   Column1 = c(10, 20, 30),
                   Column2 = c(40, 50, 60))
```

Say I assign category A to Column1 and and category C to Column2. I want to multiply the row value from Column1 with the row betas from category A, *if the dates match*. Similarly, I want to multiply the row value from Column2 with the row betas from category C, *if the dates match*.

The match between a category and a column is of my own choosing. Assigning this myself won’t be a problem I think because I have relatively few columns.

Preferably, I want the output to look like this:

```
results <- data.frame(Date = c(2001, 2002, 2003),
                      Column1_categoryA_beta1 = c(10, 60, 120),
                      Column1_categoryA_beta2 = c(20, 80, 180),
                      Column2_categoryC_beta1 = c(200, 150, 60),
                      Column2_categoryC_beta2 = c(200, 200, 120))
```

Any help in how I best can approach this problem is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some data wrangling using `tidyr` and `dplyr` this can be achieved like so:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(Category = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
                  Date = c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003),
                  Beta1 = c(1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 5, 3, 1),
                  Beta2 = c(2, 4, 6, 1, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2))

df2 <- data.frame(Date = c(2001, 2002, 2003),
                  Column1 = c(10, 20, 30),
                  Column2 = c(40, 50, 60))


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2_long <- df2 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Date, names_to = "Column", values_to = "Value") %>% 
  mutate(Category = ifelse(Column == "Column1", "A", "C"))

df2_long %>% 
  left_join(df1) %>% 
  mutate(Beta1 = Value * Beta1,
         Beta2 = Value * Beta2) %>% 
  select(Date, Category, Column, Beta1, Beta2) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Date, names_from = c("Column", "Category"), values_from = c("Beta1", "Beta2"))
#> Joining, by = c("Date", "Category")
#> Warning: Column `Category` joining character vector and factor, coercing into
#> character vector
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>    Date Beta1_Column1_A Beta1_Column2_C Beta2_Column1_A Beta2_Column2_C
#>   <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
#> 1  2001              10             200              20             200
#> 2  2002              60             150              80             200
#> 3  2003             120              60             180             120
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

One way to get there while keeping the `Category` variable in the final data frame is the following:

```
df3 <- left_join(df1, df2, by="Date")
df4 <- df3 %>%
  group_by(Date, Category) %>%
  mutate(Col1Bet1 = Column1 * Beta1, Col1Bet2 = Column1 * Beta2, Col2Bet1 = Column2 * Beta1, Col2Bet2 = Column2 * Beta2)
```

which gives the following:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 10
# Groups:   Date, Category [9]
  Category  Date Beta1 Beta2 Column1 Column2 Col1Bet1 Col1Bet2 Col2Bet1 Col2Bet2
  <fct>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 A         2001     1     2      10      40       10       20       40       80
2 A         2002     3     4      20      50       60       80      150      200
3 A         2003     4     6      30      60      120      180      240      360
4 B         2001     4     1      10      40       40       10      160       40
5 B         2002     5     1      20      50      100       20      250       50
6 B         2003     3     2      30      60       90       60      180      120
7 C         2001     5     5      10      40       50       50      200      200
8 C         2002     3     4      20      50       60       80      150      200
9 C         2003     1     2      30      60       30       60       60      120
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a start. The result data.table has all information you want just in another format.

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2)
df3$b1 <- ifelse(df3$Category=="A", df3$Beta1*df3$Column1, ifelse(df3$Category=="C", df3$Beta1*df3$Column2, NA))
df3$b2 <- ifelse(df3$Category=="A", df3$Beta2*df3$Column1, ifelse(df3$Category=="C", df3$Beta2*df3$Column2, NA))

# Date Category Beta1 Beta2 Column1 Column2  b1  b2
# 1 2001        A     1     2      10      40  10  20
# 2 2001        C     5     5      10      40 200 200
# 3 2001        B     4     1      10      40  NA  NA
# 4 2002        A     3     4      20      50  60  80
# 5 2002        B     5     1      20      50  NA  NA
# 6 2002        C     3     4      20      50 150 200
# 7 2003        B     3     2      30      60  NA  NA
# 8 2003        A     4     6      30      60 120 180
# 9 2003        C     1     2      30      60  60 120
```